# How to hide only clicked button belonging to same class of buttons using Vanilla JS HTML CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, json

I am stuck with situation where I am rendering a data.json into HTML using JS.
Everything is working fine. Json data is rendered into html using loop which results in multiple objects having same class.

Because of this every button I created belongs to same class in loop.
Now the question; I want to hide only specific button that is clicked and not all the buttons of the class.

```js
var X = document.getElementsByClassName("buttons");
function HideClickedButton() {

  for (let x of X) {
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
      x.style.display = "block";
    
    } else {
      x.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}

for (const button of X) {
    button.addEventListener('click', HideClickedButton);
}
```

```html
<button class="buttons">Test</button>
<button class="buttons">Test</button>
<button class="buttons">Test</button>
<button class="buttons">Test</button>
```

the above code is hiding all the buttons of the same class.

and if use only `document.querySelector(".buttons").style.display = "none"`

Then it is always hiding the first button no matter which button is pressed.

**Edited Part:**

```
 <div onclick="addToCart(${product.price})">
    <button class="b1" onclick="hideAddButton(this)" type="button">ADD</button>
  </div>
  <div onclick="addToCartRemove(${product.price})">
    <button class="b2 hidden" onclick="showRemoveButton(this)" type="button">Remove</button>
  </div>
```

So. my code is something like this in JS which is basically rendering list from JSON. After rendering, totals buttons are 12.
In a group of 6 (see image). Now, I don't want to show remove button initially. It will only show when corresponding ADD button is clicked. When ADD button is clicked it will hide and Remove button will takes it place while other ADD buttons remains the same. Please let me know if you understand.[image]

Comment: It's hard to tell how you expect this logic to work, the function is just toggling the visibility state of all the buttons. The easiest way is to pass the event target into the handler so it knows which one was clicked and you can act accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using onclick="yourfunction(this)" , please see snippet below.

Other solution is to use an event listener.

```js
function HideClickedButton(x) {
      x.style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button onclick="HideClickedButton(this)" class="buttons">Button 1</button>
  <button onclick="HideClickedButton(this)" class="buttons">Button 2</button>
  <button onclick="HideClickedButton(this)" class="buttons">Button 3</button>
  <button onclick="HideClickedButton(this)" class="buttons">Button 4</button>
</div>
```

EDIT : Following your question in the comments, here is how to toggle display of button 1 when clicking button 8, and vice versa.
It does not matter which class are the buttons because it is the onclick attribute that triggers the function, not their class.

```js
function HideClickedButton(x) {
      var parent = x.parentNode;
      var index = [].indexOf.call(parent.children, x);
      //if clicked element is index 0 in parent element's children (button 1)
      if(index==0){
        //show element index 7 (button 8)
        parent.children[7].style.display = "inline-block"; 
      }
      //else if clicked element is index 7 in parent element's children (button 8)
      else if(index==7){
        //hide or show element index 0 (button 1)
        parent.children[0].style.display = "inline-block"; 
      }
      //we hide clicked button
        x.style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button onclick="HideClickedButton(this)" class="buttons">Button 1</button>
  <button onclick="HideClickedButton(this)" class="buttons">Button 2</button>
  <button onclick="HideClickedButton(this)" class="buttons">Button 3</button>
  <button onclick="HideClickedButton(this)" class="buttons">Button 4</button>
  <button onclick="HideClickedButton(this)" class="buttons">Button 5</button>
  <button onclick="HideClickedButton(this)" class="buttons">Button 6</button>
  <button onclick="HideClickedButton(this)" class="buttons">Button 7</button>
  <button onclick="HideClickedButton(this)" class="buttons_other_class">Button 8</button>
</div>
```

Comment: It seems to be working. Now is it possible to show others buttons of different class? For example if button 1 is pressed it will hide and show button8 (of different class). And if again button 8 is clicked it will show again button 1 and vice versa.

Comment: @AhsanAli yes I am going to edit my snippet

Comment: @AhsanAli I have edited my snippet to allow toggling button 1 & button 8. Please upvote if that was useful :)

Comment: it seems to be not working. The buttons are in separate divs and if 1 is press it will show 8 and vice versa. But in you above code all the buttons are visible initially.

Comment: @AhsanAli ok I think I understood better what you wanted. I have edited my snippet : now when you click on button 1, it disappears and shows button 8. When you click on button 8, it disappears and shows button 1. Buttons are not in different divs, but they were on different lines because of adding "block" display. This is why I have used "inline-block" in my edited snippet so they stay on the same line. Please tell me if that is the result you wanted

Comment: Lucas, I have edited my original post. please see last paragraph to understand.

Comment: Not completely solved but helped me in next steps.

Answer (score 1):

Either [attach a listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to [each button](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and [`hide`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) the element [that was clicked on](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/Comparison_of_Event_Targets)...

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.button');

buttons.forEach(button => {
  addEventListener('click', handleClick)
});

function handleClick(e) {
  e.target.classList.add('hide');
}
```

```css
.hide { display: none; }
```

```html
<button class="button">one</button>
<button class="button">two</button>
<button class="button">three</button>
<button class="button">four</button>
<button class="button">five</button>
```

...or [wrap your buttons in a container](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector), use [event delegation](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-event-delegation/) and only attach *one* listener to that container (this will capture all the events from its child elements as they "bubble up" the DOM). [Check the clicked element has class `.button`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches), and then hide it.

```js
const buttons = document.querySelector('.buttons');

buttons.addEventListener('click', handleClick);

function handleClick(e) {
  if (e.target.matches('.button')) {
    e.target.classList.add('hide');
  }
}
```

```css
.hide { display: none; }
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
  <button class="button">one</button>
  <button class="button">two</button>
  <button class="button">three</button>
  <button class="button">four</button>
  <button class="button">five</button>
</div>
```

Comment: If you are going to suggest event delegation, you need to make sure you ignore clicks that are not on the buttons. If you click outside of them, all the buttons are deleted at once.

Comment: I did have that I just stuck it on the wrong snippet :) Thanks for spotting it @JuanMendes

Comment: @Andy I am not sure why but eventlistener is not working for me. Onclick is working well. Could you please take a look at the original post as I have edited and added the picture.? Thank you

Comment: `addEventListener` not `eventListener`.

Comment: @Andy still not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an event listener for the click of your button.

```js
var X = document.getElementsByClassName("buttons");
    X.forEach(function (element) {
        element.addEventListener("click", function () {
            this.style.display = "none";
        })
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

1. document.querySelector() is only going to select the first element than matches the selector. You need document.querySelectorAll() to get all elements that match.
2. But you can do this much easier by attaching to the event handler's for all your buttons once they are rendered.

You sort of imply that the button that is clicked should disappear, and the other buttons should reappear. If this is not the case you can comment out the line of code below that change the style of "other" buttons to block.

Edit: e.PreventDefault() and e.StopPropagation() are there to prevent standard button click behavior (submitting forms and whatnot.) If you do not want to suppress this behavior, you can simply remove these lines.

```js
const buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('buttons');

[...buttons].forEach( (button) => {
   button.addEventListener( 
      'click', 
      (e) => HideClickedButton( e, button ), 
      false 
   );
});

function HideClickedButton( e, button ) {
  [...buttons].forEach( (other) => other.style.display = 'block' );
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  button.style.display = 'none';
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button class="buttons">Button 1</button>
  <button class="buttons">Button 2</button>
  <button class="buttons">Button 3</button>
  <button class="buttons">Button 4</button>
</div>
```